# Find the maximum of a non-linear function with 4 parameters

Tags: functions

I'm trying to find the maximum of a function with 4 positive parameters :
$$f(x,y,z,t)=$$$$(-2(x+5)^2+200x)+(-2(y+10)^2+200y)+(-2(z+15)^2+200z)+(-2t^2+200t)$$
with $x+y+z+t = 150$

I don't know if this is feasible and how to proceed.
I have try to reduce the function with $t = 150-x-y-z$
But I don't know what to do after that.
If you have any hint or link I would really appreciate.
Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Are you supposed to use optimization with Lagrange mutlipliers ? If yes, the problem is very simple. If such a solution is of any interest to you, just post and I shall add the path to solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in Nemo's reply.
$$\begin{align}
f(x,y,z,t)&=-2\left( \left( x+5 \right) ^{ 2 }+\left( y+10 \right) ^{ 2 }+\left( z+15 \right) ^{ 2 }+t^{ 2 } \right) +200\left( x+y+z+t \right)
\\
&=-2\left( \left( x+5 \right) ^{ 2 }+\left( y+10 \right) ^{ 2 }+\left( z+15 \right) ^{ 2 }+t^{ 2 } \right) +200\cdot 150
\\
&=-2\left( \left( x+5 \right) ^{ 2 }+\left( y+10 \right) ^{ 2 }+\left( z+15 \right) ^{ 2 }+t^{ 2 } \right) +30000\,,
\end{align}$$
if $x+y+z+t=150$. 
Now, by the Power-Mean Inequality (Cauchy-Schwarz, AM-QM, Holder, AM-GM, Rearrangement, or whatever you prefer), we have
$$\begin{align}
\frac{(x+5)^2+(y+10)^2+(z+15)^2+t^2}{4}&\geq \left(\frac{(x+5)+(y+10)+(z+15)+t}{4}\right)^2
\\
&=\left(\frac{(x+y+z+t)+30}{4}\right)^2
\\
&=\left(\frac{150+30}{4}\right)^2=45^2=2025\,.
\end{align}$$
That is, 
$$f(x,y,z,t)\leq -2\cdot 4\cdot 2025+30000=-16200+30000=13800\,.$$
The maximum is attained iff $x+5=y+10=z+15=t=45$, or $(x,y,z,t)=(40,35,30,45)$.

Comment: How do you find that the parameters are 40,35,30,45 ?

Comment: That's the equality condition for the Power-Mean Inequality.

Answer (score 0):

$$-2\left[ \left( x+5 \right) ^{ 2 }+\left( y+10 \right) ^{ 2 }+\left( z+15 \right) ^{ 2 }+t^{ 2 } \right] +200\left[ x+y+z+t \right] =-2\left[ \left( x+5 \right) ^{ 2 }+\left( y+10 \right) ^{ 2 }+\left( z+15 \right) ^{ 2 }+t^{ 2 } \right] +200\cdot 150=\\ =-2\left[ \left( x+5 \right) ^{ 2 }+\left( y+10 \right) ^{ 2 }+\left( z+15 \right) ^{ 2 }+t^{ 2 } \right] +30000$$

**Edit** my answer is not complite.

Comment: This only proves that the function is bounded above by 30000. It's not achievable with the constraint.

Comment: what is the max of $f\left( x \right)=-2\left( x+5 \right) ^{ 2 }+10\\ $?

Comment: @Nemo: $x,y,z,t$ are positive such that $x+y+z+t=150$.

Comment: yes I see,i didn't care about about positive x,y,z,t,i wil correct my answer

Answer (score 0):

Since $t=150-x-y-z$, we have
$$\begin{align}\\&f(x,y,z)=-2(x+5)^2+200x-2(y+10)^2+200y-2(z+15)^2+200z-2(150-x-y-z)^2+200(150-x-y-z)\\&=-4 x^2-4 x y-4 x z+580 x-4 y^2-4 y z+560 y-4 z^2+540 z-15700\\&=-4x^2+(-4y-4z+580)x-4 y^2-4 y z+560 y-4 z^2+540 z-15700\\&=-4\left(x+\frac{y+z-145}{2}\right)^2+(-y-z+145)^2-4 y^2-4 y z+560 y-4 z^2+540 z-15700\\&=-4\left(x+\frac{y+z-145}{2}\right)^2-3 y^2-2 y z+270 y-3 z^2+250 z+5325\\&=-4\left(x+\frac{y+z-145}{2}\right)^2-3y^2+(-2z+270)y-3 z^2+250 z+5325\\&=-4\left(x+\frac{y+z-145}{2}\right)^2-3\left(y-\frac{-z+135}{3}\right)^2+\frac{(-z+135)^2}{3}-3 z^2+250 z+5325\\&=-4\left(x+\frac{y+z-145}{2}\right)^2-3\left(y-\frac{-z+135}{3}\right)^2-\frac 83(z-30)^2+13800\end{align}$$
Hence, the maximum is $\color{red}{13800}$ for $(x,y,z,t)=(40,35,30,45)$.